# Is the glob syntax used by Mercurial cross-platform?

Tags: mercurial, glob

I started getting creative with my glob syntax in my `.hgignore` file to compress groups of lines (similar extensions, etc) into one.  However, in reading the [WP Glob syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Syntax) article section, I'm left with the question if this will break on my colleagues' Windows boxes.

Is Mercurial parsing the globs itself or does it leave it to the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial does the parsing itself, or at least in a cross-platform way through its python code. I've shared complex ignores across platforms without problems.